# How to loop canvas animation?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to understand animations. It seems that I am always stuck when I need to create the loop. So, I have two different styles and I want them to interchange every couple of seconds, or 1 second, doesn't matter.

```js
document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("square").style.border = "2px solid black";
const c = document.getElementById("square");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const repaint = () => {
  document.getElementById("square").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 200, 200);
  ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
  ctx.fillRect(600, 200, 200, 200);
};

const draw = () => {
  if (c.getContext) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(800, 200);
    ctx.moveTo(400, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(400, 400);
    ctx.moveTo(200, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 400);
    ctx.moveTo(600, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(600, 400);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 200, 200);
    ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
    ctx.fillRect(600, 200, 200, 200);
  } else {
    // canvas-unsupported code here
  }
};

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
setInterval(repaint, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Animated flag</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>

  </div>
  <canvas id="square" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="./red-white-animation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want to achieve happens only once in this example. Red squares switch to white, and white to red. How to achieve this behavior to happen continuously?

I have these two functions and my idea was to switch between them every couple of seconds, but as much as I read about canvas and animations, I can't wrap my head around this and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the function that you are calling every 1000ms with setInterval draws the same pattern. You call requestAnimationFrame once, which is going to be applied once in the render stage of the event loop, and the function passed to requestAnimationFrame will never be called again. Instead you repeatedly apply the code inside repaint with setInterval. If you want repaint to draw a different pattern every time, you should keep track of a global state variable which indicates what pattern to draw next

```
let drawState = 0
 
const repaint = () => {
   if (drawState) {
      // clear and redraw the first pattern
   }
   else {
     // clear and redraw the second pattern
   }
   drawState ^= 1;
}
```

But there is even a bigger problem with your code. setInterval is a deprecated way of animating with JS. This is because the function passed to setInterval is executed in a different part of the event loop, than the render part. requestAnimationFrame was made just for this reason - it attaches the function passed to it right before the contents of the page are rendered during each frame. So your code should only make use of requestAnimationFrame and looks something like this

```
function animate() {
    // call functions for drawing the frame
    ...

    // Prepare the animation code execution for the next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Knowing that there are 60 frames executed per 1000ms, you can achieve the timing by changing the patter for every 60th call to animate().

I recommend you read more on JS event loop and requestAnimationFrame.